# EOT file wont work in any browser

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

My eot fot file wont work in any browser. The main one im concerned about is internet explorer since thats the browser the file is made for. Ive tried the standard code, changing the font family name to match the actual font name and modifying htaccess but none of those slutions worked. What else an I do to get this to work?

```
@font-face {
       font-family: "poiret";
        src: url('PoiretOne-Regular.ttf') format("truetype"); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
     url('../skins/MonoBook/PoiretOne-Regular.eot');  /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
    url('skins/MonoBook/PoiretOne-Regular.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype');  /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the eot file was corrupt. I ue google font poiret one instead and the font now works in all browers including ie explorer which was th one I was concerned about.